# CakePHP 4.x Authentication 2.x - Installation failed. Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of package

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to install CakePHP 4.x Authentication 2.x, but this error appears when I try to run this command

> composer require "cakephp/authentication:^2.0"

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/authentication 2.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/authentication[2.0.0].
    - cakephp/authentication 2.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-diactoros ^2.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-diactoros[2.0.0, ..., 2.2.1].
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.2.1.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.2.0.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.5.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.4.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.3.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.2.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.1.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.1.0.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.0.3.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.0.2.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.0.1.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.8.0 conflicts with zendframework/zend-diactoros 2.0.0.
    - cakephp/cakephp 4.2.10 requires laminas/laminas-diactoros ^2.2.2 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-diactoros[2.8.0].
    - cakephp/cakephp is locked to version 4.2.10 and an update of this package was not requested.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Why do you want version 2.0? The current is version 2.6. Just `composer require cakephp/authentication` should get that for you?

Comment: 5 dollars that you're using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg Schmidt mentioned, the latest version for cakephp authentication is version 2.6. So I just installed the latest version by running

```
composer require "cakephp/authentication:^2.6"
```